# What's the difference between Float#floor and Float#to_i in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, numbers

I'm learning Ruby, and I'm currently in numbers. So as I understand it, there are five ways (perhaps more) to coerce integers and floats to each other:

- `Integer#to_f`: Coerce to a new float
- `Float#ceil`: Round up to the nearest integer
- `Float#floor`: Round down to the nearest integer
- `Float#round`: Round to the nearest integer
- `Float#to_i`: Truncate to the nearest integer

What's the difference between "rounding down" and "truncating" to the nearest integer?

When I tested it...

```rb
puts 34.4.to_i()
puts 34.4.floor()
```

... it resulted in the same values:

```
34
34
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `to_i` basically only removes decimals from the float. Whereas `float` rounds down to the next lower integer. The difference is easier to see when dealing with negative floats:

```
-34.4.floor
#=> -35

-34.4.to_i
#=> -34
```

And it might be worth noting that [`Float#round`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Float.html#method-i-round) supports different rounding modes.

```
`:up` or `nil`: round away from zero:

2.5.round(half: :up)      # => 3
3.5.round(half: :up)      # => 4
(-2.5).round(half: :up)   # => -3

`:down`: round toward zero:

2.5.round(half: :down)    # => 2
3.5.round(half: :down)    # => 3
(-2.5).round(half: :down) # => -2

`:even`: round toward the candidate whose last nonzero digit is even:

2.5.round(half: :even)    # => 2
3.5.round(half: :even)    # => 4
(-2.5).round(half: :even) # => -2
```

Answer (score 6):

- `floor` (without arguments) returns the next integer less than or equal to the receiver
- `ceil` (without arguments) returns the next integer greater than or equal to the receiver
- `to_i` discards the fractional part of the receiver and returns the integer part

| f | f.to_i | f.floor | f.ceil | f.round |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11.8 | 11 | 11 | 12 | 12 |
| 11.5 | 11 | 11 | 12 | 12 |
| 11.2 | 11 | 11 | 12 | 11 |
| 11.0 | 11 | 11 | 11 | 11 |
| -11.2 | -11 | -12 | -11 | -11 |
| -11.5 | -11 | -12 | -11 | -12 |
| -11.8 | -11 | -12 | -11 | -12 |

`to_i` behaves like `floor` for positive numbers and like `ceil` for negative numbers.

In fact, that's actually how `Float#to_i` is implemented in [`numeric.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v3_2_2/numeric.c#L2597-L2606):

```c
static VALUE
flo_to_i(VALUE num)
{
    double f = RFLOAT_VALUE(num);

    if (f > 0.0) f = floor(f);
    if (f < 0.0) f = ceil(f);

    return dbl2ival(f);
}
```

There's also [`truncate`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.2/Float.html#method-i-truncate) which behaves like `to_i` but takes an optional number of digits (like `floor`, `ceil`, and `round`).

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers as correct, but thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Maybe you could add 10.5 and -10.5 in the table to also document whether round rounds to nearest even or away from zero in case of exact tie...